# Cómo cambiar valores en una columna de dataframe

Tags: r

Hoy empecé con unos amigos a aprender R, tenemos un ejercicio de cambiar los valores de sexo en un dataframe.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar de una forma que sea más directa, es decir, los que son `F` cambiarlos a `M` y viceversa?

```
 Nombres Edad Altura Peso Sexo
1    Alexa   25    177   57    F
2    Lilly   31    163   69    F
3     Mark   23    190   63    M
4   Oliver   52    179   75    M
5   Martha   76    163   70    F
6    Lucas   49    183   83    M
7 Carolina   26    164   53    F

Así fue como lo hice

#--Ejercicio 1 Crear data frame

Nombres = c ("Alexa","Lilly","Mark","Oliver","Martha","Lucas","Carolina")
Edad = c (25,31,23,52,76,49,26)
Altura = c(177,163,190,179,163,183,164)
Peso = c(57,69,63,75,70,83,53)
Sexo = c("F","F","M","M","F","M","F")
```

Comment: Hola. En todas las preguntas conviene que agregues el código con lo que intentaste hasta ahora, de esa forma, vas a recibir una ayuda más informada que apunte sobre lo importante de donde estás teniendo problemas. Te invito a [edit] la pregunta agregando el código

Answer (score 1):

Si el cambio que quieres realizar es únicamente binario (solo conlleva dos valores), puedes utilizar la función `ifelse()`,

```
df$Sexo <- ifelse(df$Sexo == 'F', 'M', 'F')
```

Ésta se puede interpretar así:

```
destino <- ifelse(condicion, valor si la condicion se cumple, valor si la condicion no se cumple)
```

Ahora, si quieres incluir más de dos valores posibles en el cambio que quieres realizar, entonces podrías emplear la función `transmute()` de la paquetería `dplyr`, la cual debes instalar y cargar así,

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Y la función se usa así,

```
df <- transmute(df, Sexo = case_when(Sexo == 'M' ~ 'F',
                                     Sexo == 'F' ~ 'M'))
```

La función `transmute()` crea una nueva columna a partir del valor de otras columnas, las cuales elimina al finalizar. En el ejemplo de arriba, la función está haciendo algo como esto,

```
destino <- transmute(origen, nueva_columna = case_when(valor de vieja columna ~ valor de nueva columna))
```

Con esta función puedes poner cuantas condiciones y nuevos valores como quieras.

P.D. Si quieres crear nuevas columnas sin eliminar columnas antiguas, solamente cambia `transmute` por `mutate`. Todo lo demás se queda igual.